# Running a task approximately every minute without using Thread.Sleep

Tags: c#, timer

I have a method in C# that I would run, then wait a minute before restarting the method again.

Right now, I am just using

```
while(true)
{
    this.DoMyMethod();

    Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1));
}
```

While this works, I am wondering if there is a more elegant way of doing this? The issue with Timers, is they'll run even if the last timer fire call hasn't finished yet.

Comment: `The issue with Timers, is they'll run even if the last timer fire call hasn't finished yet.` So why not have some boolean check to see if the last fire call has finished?

Comment: System.Threading.Timer, if you are on the .NET 4 or lower, while + Task.Delay otherwise.

Comment: `The issue with Timers, is they'll run even if the last timer fire call hasn't finished yet.` Some timers do this, and some don't, and in either case, checking this yourself is trivial, as has already been mentioned.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With `System.Timers.Timer` you can set `AutoReset` to `false` meaning the timer will only run once, you'd have to call `Start()` again to restart it.

So in your timer tick method simply call `Start()` after you've done what you need to and you're ready to begin again.

For example:

```
public SomeClass()
{
    Timer timer = new Timer(60000);
    timer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(OnElapsed);
    timer.AutoReset = false;
    timer.Start();
}

private void OnElapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    // Do stuff

    timer.Start(); // Restart timer
}
```

Answer (score 8):

So make an asynchronous loop:

```
public async Task DoMyThing(CancellationToken token = default(CancellationToken))
{
     while(!token.IsCancellationRequested)
     {
         this.DoMyMethod();
         try
         {
             await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1), token);
         }
         catch(TaskCanceledException)
         {
             break;
         }
     }
}
```

This code is guaranteed not to overlap the invocations of `DoMyMethod`, so the delay (much in the same way as `Thread.Sleep`) happens *between* invocations.

If you create a `CancellationTokenSource`, you can pass its `Token` to your method and you can kill the loop by calling `Cancel` on the `CancellationTokenSource`.

Note: `CancellationToken.None === default(CancellationToken)`

Answer (score 2):

A timer is still your option.  If you are concerned about it tripping again before the first timer firing process has completed, the stop the timer while the process runs, and then restart it when your process completes.